# django ...Could not parse the remainder: ''css/materialize.min.css’' from ''css/materialize.min.css’'

Tags: css, django

I do follow a tutorial where is add a chat bot ui...the ui is embedded in django.. the structure looks the following...

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── installDjango.sh
├── manage.py
├── rasadjango
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── rasaweb
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── lib
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

static folder

```
.
├── css
│   ├── materialize.min.css
│   └── style.css
├── img
│   ├── banner.png
│   ├── body.png
│   ├── botAvatar_old.png
└── js
    ├── chart.min.js
    ├── jquery.min.js
    ├── materialize.min.js
    └── script.js
```

in the rasadjango/settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

when run ...

```
python manage.py runserver
```

i get an error

```
Could not parse the remainder: ''css/materialize.min.css’' from ''css/materialize.min.css’'
```

part of my index.html file...on top i do load the static....

```
{% load static %}
....

   <link rel= “stylesheet” type= “text/css” href= ”{% static 'css/materialize.min.css’ %}”>
...
```

What is wrong...

Comment: wrong closing quote symbol `'css/materialize.min.css’`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error might be very subtle with the character used to close the argument in your static tag.

In the line,

```
<link rel= “stylesheet” type= “text/css” href= ”{% static 'css/materialize.min.css’ %}”>
```

You have a ` character instead of a ' character.

Replace the line with

```
<link rel= “stylesheet” type= “text/css” href= ”{% static 'css/materialize.min.css' %}”>
```

Comment: You should accept this as answer since this is obviously the cause of your problem @MMM